How to create more detailed log of unit tests?
The objective will be to be able to generate a document with a more detailed restitution of the tests carried out than what the framework offers; with input data, result data and an explanatory sentence.
On ADT restitution we have

Nothing more than the name of the test methods and the result.
On SAP GUI restitution we have

Would it be possible to add messages or even analysis for a test (successfull also) ?
Or do you know if there is a specific solution that allows you to do this ?
Otherwise I'm getting into dev. For example an assertion class which adds logs and the possibility of recovering logs following tests.

You may log a message without failure via the parameters level and quit of cl_abap_unit_assert methods (use fail if there's no condition) e.g. level = cl_aunit_assert=>tolerable and quit = cl_aunit_assert=>no. Nothing more.

Thanks, it's a twist but it works for what i want :-)
